Using UnitOfWork's get body more than once returns empty body
Previously I was using camel version 2.x.x. The getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage().getBody() was something used throughout the code and even called twice or thrice in the same exchange.
However, in camel version 4.x.x whenever I try to call it more than once it returns an empty body, in the first call it returns proper body but in the second the body is empty. The documentation says to set AllowUseOriginalMessage as true and I've done so in properties file
camel.main.allowUseOriginalMessage= true
camel.springboot.allow-use-original-message = true 

Anything else I can change? As this is used quite heavily in the code I'd prefer a way to have it working as the camel 2.x.x version.

Do you have stream caching enabled? If not, and the body is a stream, reading it more than once can be unpredictable.

The doc says since 3.x.x it's true by default. But just in case I did set it and try and still the same issue.
